# Workbook could not be assigned

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Set xlobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlobj.DisplayAlerts = 0

    xlobj.Workbooks.Open wbPathName & "\" & wbList(intListCounter), True, True
    DoEvents

    Dim wBk As Workbook


    Set wBk = Workbooks(wbList(intListCounter))


    MsgBox wBk
```

Hi,

I have the above workbook. The line where "Set wBk =" is getting a subscript out of range error.

Whats inside "wbList(intListCounter)" here is correct as it points to a xlsm file with the extension.

However, I suspect "xlobj.Workbooks.Open" is the culprit but could not pin point the error as some of the above is written by a prior consultant.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem, you're creating a new instance of Excel.Application class, but then you're trying to open the workbook from the Active (i.e., the instance in which this procedure is running). Since the file is **not** open in the active/running instance, the error is expected.

You could resolve by:

```
Set wBk = xlobj.Workbooks(wbList(intListCounter))
```

But that seems rather hacky, and makes from code that will be difficult to follow.

**You should assign to the Workbook object variable *while* opening the file**

```
Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim xlObj as Excel.Application

Set xlobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlobj.DisplayAlerts = 0
Set wBk = xlobj.Workbooks.Open(wbPathName & "\" & wbList(intListCounter), True, True)
```

Further, you may not need to create a new Excel instance (there are some times when this is necessary, but I think most times it is not necessary), in which case you can simply do:

```
Dim wbK as Workbook
Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(wbPathName & "\" & wbList(intListCounter), True, True)
```

Also, note that this line will raise a 438 error:

```
MsgBox wBk
```

Do this instead, if needed:

```
MsgBox wBk.Name
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm!

Quick side question:
"code" xlobj.Workbooks.Open wbPathName & "\" & wbList(intListCounter), True, True "code'"

Whats the "True, True" at the end of above line indicates?

Comment: That's specifying `True` parameter for `UpdateLinks` and `ReadOnly`.

Comment: You can find out almost anything from the [Excel Object Model Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068(v=office.14).aspx), just drill down to the appropriate object/method/etc.

Comment: Thanks again! That was very helpful!